# Mouse position in jQuery Dialog open function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

How to get a mouse position inside open function of jQuery Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

tried [google](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position)?

```
$('#mydialog').mousemove(function(e){
    var offset = $('#mydialog').offset()

    // e.pageX - offset.left
    // e.pageY - offset.top
});
```

**Edit re: comment**

afaik the mouse coordinates are only available on mousemove. You will need to use something like `$('html').mousemove` to constantly capture the coords to global vars, then do something with them on open

Comment: I said, "inside open function"

Comment: He Said "inside open function"!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
   open: function(event, ui)
   {
        var offset = $('#mydialog').offset();
        var P_LX = e.pageX - offset.left
        var P_TY = e.pageY - offset.top
   }
});
```

Comment: plagiarise... I was not plagiarising your code, yes i used, merely to save time writing it... there's no other way to write that code, apart from variable renaming. get a grip.